# Hide background-image overflow equally from left and right

Tags: css, background-image

Lets say I have a div with width of **100px** and I have an image with **UNKNOWN** width.

Is there any way that I set the image as the background of the div with the following requirements:

- If the image is wider than div  **HIDE overflow from both sides of the image EQUALLY**
- If the image is smaller or equal of the div  make it **100%** of the width of the div

Comment: Yes you can easily do this with JavaScript

Comment: Use `background-size:cover;`

Answer (score 3):

A CSS `background-image` won't afford you this level of flexibility, but you can approximate it with an `<img>`:

```css
div {
  /* We'll be positioning the <img> relative to the <div>. */
  position: relative;
  
  /* Don't let an oversized background image stretch out the <div>. */
  overflow: hidden;
}

div>img {
  /* Since the image is an <img> element and not a background-image,
  we don't have to worry about it shrinking, but we do need to
  explicitly make it no smaller than the containing <div>. */
  min-width: 100%;
  
  /* Don't get in the way of positioning other elements. */
  position: absolute;
  
  /* Move the left edge of the image to the center of the <div>, then
  shift it back by half the width of the <img>. Result: centered
  image. */
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  
  /* It's supposed to be a background image, so put it behind other
  content. */
  z-index: -1;
}


/* The rest is just for the sake of this example. */
div {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  resize: both;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXLKG.png">
  Try resizing this &lt;div>!
</div>
```

Comment: doesn't need to be absolute, you can use `margin-left: 50%` instead of absolute and left propertiy

Answer (score 0):

background image is not able scale size with container.

Comment: `background-size: cover` does this? "Resize the background image to cover the entire container, even if it has to stretch the image or cut a little bit off one of the edges" (W3Schools)

Answer (score 0):

Making the content `width : 100%` of its parent will work here!

```css
.fixSize{
  width:500px;
}
.image{
  width:100%
}
```

```html
<!-- Now if i have a large image width:2500px -->
<div class="fixSize">
 <img class= "image" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg" alt="Large Image">
</div>

<!-- Now if i have a small image width:256px -->
<div class="fixSize">
 <img class= "image" src="https://digitalpadm.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Logarithmic-Image-Gray-level-Transformation-digitalpadm.bmp" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy fix with JavaScript 
Html code

```
<div id="dv">
      <img id="img" src="yourImageSource"/>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
#dv {
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 2px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#img {
    height: 200px;
}
```

JavaScript code

```
window.onload = ()=>{
    var a = document.getElementById("dv");
    var b = document.getElementById("img")
    var c = a.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    var d = b.getBoundingClientRect().width;

    if(c < d){
        b.style.marginLeft = (c - d)/2 + "px";
        b.style.width = "auto";
    } else {
        b.style.marginLeft = "0px";
        b.style.width = "100%";
    }
}
```